# how to get an access to array in defferent classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, properties, nsmutablearray

i created an array(NSMutablearray) in my AppDelegate by using @property and i cannot get  access to this array in other classes(although i used #import "AppDelegate").

here is the deceleration of my array property:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *photoArray;
```

here is my array initialize(Appdelegate.m):

```
    photoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    PhotoItem *photo1 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"] name:@"roy rest"  photographer:@"roy"];
    PhotoItem *photo2 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"] name:@"roy's hand" photographer:@"roy"];
    PhotoItem *photo3 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"] name:@"sapir first" photographer:@"sapir"];
    PhotoItem *photo4 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"] name:@"sapir second" photographer:@"sapir"];
    [photoArray addObject:photo1];
    [photoArray addObject:photo2];
    [photoArray addObject:photo3];
    [photoArray addObject:photo4];
```

now, i want to get access to the array's objects in other class, how can i do this?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To access your AppDelegate properties, you have to get an instance of your delegate.

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.photoArray //Do something
```

This allows you to access it by using delegate.photoArray.

There are a few other ways, but this is quick and easy for just simple access.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class and name it something like commonData to keep that array and common data which you want to use among screens.

Comment: Apple Docs on this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html